# Passing arbitrary objects to child processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Let's say I want to use the following class to share memory between processes:

```
class SharedNumpyArray:
    def __init__(self, shape, dtype=np.float64):
        self.shape = shape
        self.dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
        self.buf_size = self.dtype.itemsize * np.prod(shape)
        self.__buf = RawArray('b', self.buf_size)
        self.init_buf()

    def init_buf(self):
        self.buf = np.frombuffer(self.__buf, dtype=self.dtype).reshape(self.shape)
```

What happens when I pass an object to a child process?

When an instance of this class is passed to a child process, `init_buf` needs to be called again in that process. Is there a way to automate this?

Also, what happens with `__buf` if it's already defined when the instance is passed to the child process?

I think that if I make sure `self.__buf = None` before passing the instance of the class to the child processes, and then I make sure each one of them call `init_buf`, everything should work just fine, but is there a better way?

I suspect the implementation details vary a lot between different OSes as some fork processes (e.g. Linux) whereas others create new one from scratch (e.g. Windows).

Comment: How do you pass your `SharedNumpyArray` objects to your child process to begin with?

Comment: @JohanL I delved a little into multiprocessing's code and found a satisfying solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object is *actually* passed to a child process when the parent calls the `start` method of the `Process` instance associated with the child process.

Objects are passed through serialization by using `multiprocessing`'s own variant of `pickle`. This means that all we need to do is add a `__reduce__` method to our class.

Example (Python 3):

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray
import numpy as np


def _rebuild(shape, dtype, _buf):     # must be defined at the module level!
    return SharedNumpyArray(shape, dtype, buffer=_buf)


class SharedNumpyArray(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(subtype, shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0,
                strides=None, order=None):
        dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
        buf_size = dtype.itemsize * np.prod(shape)
        __buf = buffer or RawArray('b', int(buf_size))
        obj = super().__new__(subtype, shape, dtype, __buf, offset, strides,
                              order)
        obj.__buf = __buf
        return obj

    def __reduce__(self):
        return _rebuild, (self.shape, self.dtype, self.__buf)


class TestProc(Process):
    def __init__(self, shared_buf):
        super().__init__()
        self.shared_buf = shared_buf

    def run(self):
        self.shared_buf[0] = 12
        self.shared_buf[1:5] = 13
        self.shared_buf[1:5] *= 3


def test_proc():
    buf = SharedNumpyArray(1000, dtype=np.byte)
    p = TestProc(buf)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    assert buf[0] == 12
    assert np.all(buf[1:5] == 13 * 3)
    assert len(buf) == 1000


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_proc()
```